# stray \342 in program

Tags: arduino-uno

When I try to compile my code it says "stray '\342' in program

My code:

```
#include <IRremote2.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>


#define pinIN 11

uint32_t val;
uint32_t prev;
int fre = 0;


IRrecv remote(pinIN);
decode_results result;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  remote.enableIRIn();
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (remote.decode(&result)) {
    val = result.value;
    if (val == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
      val = prev;
    }
    prev = val;
    detekceKlaves();

    remote.resume();
  }
}

void detekceKlaves() {


  switch (val, HEX) {

    case 0x807FB24D‬:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto PLAY");
      tone(2, fre);
      break;
    case ‭0x807FB04F‬:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto STOP");
      noTone(2);
      break;
    case 0x807F18E7:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto VOL+");
      fre += 10;
      break;
    case 0x807F906F:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto VOL-");
      fre -= 10;
      break;
    case 0x807F9867:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto OFF/ON");
      fre = 0;
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Stisknuta jina klavesa");


  }
}
```

Error code:

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

irTEST:43:20: error: stray '\342' in program

     case 0x807FB24D‬:

                    ^

irTEST:43:21: error: stray '\200' in program

     case 0x807FB24D‬:

                     ^

irTEST:43:22: error: stray '\254' in program

     case 0x807FB24D‬:

                      ^

irTEST:47:10: error: stray '\342' in program

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

          ^

irTEST:47:11: error: stray '\200' in program

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

           ^

irTEST:47:12: error: stray '\255' in program

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

            ^

irTEST:47:23: error: stray '\342' in program

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

                       ^

irTEST:47:24: error: stray '\200' in program

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

                        ^

irTEST:47:25: error: stray '\254' in program

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

                         ^

C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\irTEST\irTEST.ino: In function 'void detekceKlaves()':

C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\irTEST\irTEST.ino:43:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

     case 0x807FB24D‬:

     ^~~~

C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\irTEST\irTEST.ino:47:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

     case ‭0x807FB04F‬:

     ^~~~

C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\irTEST\irTEST.ino:51:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

     case 0x807F18E7:

     ^~~~

C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\irTEST\irTEST.ino:55:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

     case 0x807F906F:

     ^~~~

C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\irTEST\irTEST.ino:59:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

     case 0x807F9867:

     ^~~~

Multiple libraries were found for "IRremote2.h"
 Used: C:\Users\maxim\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote2
exit status 1
stray '\342' in program

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Please help

Comment: possible unprintable characters ... copy the code from your question above and try to compile it

Comment: As @jsotola said, copy the code.  First try cutting and pasting into a new file.  If that does not work, copy it by retyping it into a new file.   How did you get unprintable characters?  Probably the best way (also difficult for a new developer) would be to find and use an octal editor to find and remove the problematic characters.

Comment: use something like notepad++ for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy your provided code in a vim-editor you can see some strange characters. `<202c>`

```
switch (val, HEX) {
  4 
  5     case 0x807FB24D<202c>:
  6       Serial.println("Stisknuto PLAY");
  7       tone(2, fre);
  8       break;
  9     case <202d>0x807FB04F<202c>:
```

I've removed them for you:

```
#include <IRremote2.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>

#define pinIN 11

uint32_t val;
uint32_t prev;
int fre = 0;

IRrecv remote(pinIN);
decode_results result;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  remote.enableIRIn();
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (remote.decode(&result)) 
  {
    val = result.value;
    if (val == 0xFFFFFFFF) 
    {
      val = prev;
    }
    prev = val;
    detekceKlaves();
    remote.resume();
  }
}

void detekceKlaves() 
{
  switch (val, HEX) 
  {
    case 0x807FB24D:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto PLAY");
      tone(2, fre);
      break;
    case 0x807FB04F:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto STOP");
      noTone(2);
      break;
    case 0x807F18E7:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto VOL+");
      fre += 10;
      break;
    case 0x807F906F:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto VOL-");
      fre -= 10;
      break;
    case 0x807F9867:
      Serial.println("Stisknuto OFF/ON");
      fre = 0;
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Stisknuta jina klavesa");
  }
}
```

Comment: @ MaximMaximS, you copied the code from someplace with right-to-left text orientation like an arabic website ... the hex 202d is a unicode character that controls the direction of the text ... https://www.codetable.net/hex/202d

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't copy it. I wrote it.